# asp.net jQuery JSON autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have tried to accomplish a few different ways and can't seem to make it work.

jQuery inside document.ready:

```
$('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').keyup(function() {
        if ($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val().length > 1) {
            $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../cspm/s3.asmx/SearchSrn",
                        data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "', count: '5' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.keyword
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
```

Asp.net markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSearch" runat="server" Text="Search: " Width="50px" /><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="450px" />
```

Server side web service code:

```
<WebMethod(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function SearchSrn(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()

    Dim results As New ArrayList

    Dim searchText As String() = prefixText.Split(New Char() {" "c})

    sql = New StringBuilder()
    sql.Append("select rownum,b.* from ")
    sql.Append("(select distinct a.* from imsi_keyword_lookup_b a ")
    sql.Append("where keyword like upper('%" + searchText(0).ToUpper() + "%') ")

    For i As Integer = 1 To searchText.Length - 1
        If searchText(i) <> "" Then
            sql.Append("and keyword like '%" + searchText(i).ToUpper() + "%' ")
        End If
    Next

    sql.Append("order by rank desc) b ")
    sql.Append("where rownum <= 5 ")

    Using rdr As System.Data.IDataReader = db.ExecuteDataReader(sql.ToString())
        Dim counter As Integer
        While rdr.Read
            If (counter = count) Then Exit While
            results.Add(rdr("keyword").ToString())
            counter += 1
        End While
    End Using

    Dim ResultsArray(results.Count - 1) As String
    ResultsArray = results.ToArray(GetType(System.String))
    Return ResultsArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick look at your code; i believe the Server side method should be 'Shared'

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I don't think that's it, I've used this same method with an asp.net autocomplete extender and it worked fine.  It seems like the problem is in the jquery.

Comment: is it reaching success or error states? or not running at all?

Comment: I changed to a static/shared method and the jquery is throwing an error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: what error? can you post the XMLHttpRequest.responseText from the error function?